# Restore .bkp file of different version oracle

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-12c

I have 12.1 Oracle version `.bkp` file. Can I restore it in 11.2 Oracle XE?
I have used below command:

```
 RMAN> restore controlfile from
2> '/home/db_dump/201101.BKP';
```

And now getting below error:

```
ORA-19690: backup piece release 12.1.0.0.0 incompatible with Oracle release 11.2.0.2.0
```

Please help me to figure out this or give some conclusion.

Comment: I think the error is self-explanatory. You can't go backwards

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't restore 12c backup in 11g environment.

If you need to copy data, then restore backup with 12c version and use expdp to export. After that import data to 11g.